# VSCode, Prettier and TSLint: formatOnSafe messes up auto sort of imports

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, code-formatting, tslint, prettier

I'm building React apps with TypeScript. My editor is VSCode. I use prettier and TSLint to keep my code clean.

Since a couple of projects when I hit safe prettier messes up the auto sort of imports:

Before saving:
[image: Before save]

After saving:
[image: After save]

I don't know why that currently happens, but it is definitely caused by prettier (tested it without prettier it doesn't happen).

My VSCode settings are:

```
"editor.formatOnSave": true,
"editor.formatOnType": false,
"prettier.tslintIntegration": true,
"tslint.autoFixOnSave": false,
```

And here are my TSLint settings (`tslint.json`):

```
{
  "extends": [
    "tslint:recommended",
    "tslint-eslint-rules",
    "tslint-react",
    "tslint-config-prettier"
  ],
  "jsRules": {},
  "rules": {
    "interface-name": false,
    "jsx-no-lambda": false,
    "quotemark": [true, "single", "jsx-double"]
  }
}
```

What could be the reason for this? I've used these settings with other projects before and they don't get messed up (even if I revisit them and safe now). Also it's only imports that get messed up, other than that, prettier works well.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a `.prettierrc` file to the root of your project and add the following to it:

```
{
  "singleQuote": true
}
```

I had a similar problem with Angular+Typescript, and it seems to be caused by the `singleQuote` option in Prettier. The VS Code Prettier extension has an option to set the preferred quote style, but it doesn't seem to respect that in this case.